# Play Store app link is not showing the 'changed app name' in web

Tags: android, google-play

I have changed my play store app name and it was approved 10 days ago. I have changed the poster too with the new name headline. My app link is 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farhad.myquizapp'. When I write a post or a comment with that link in web (Facebook) it shows the previous poster with previous name. But after clicking the link play store shows the actual name what I have changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the URL of the store listing cannot be changed. I think you would have to create a new app listing and change the application ID in build.gradle (Module...). And then the package name in the manifest.

The information from Google is a bit confusing about whether it's the application ID or the package name. They are independent of each other but if you don't change them yourself they are the same.

> Remember that APKs with different application IDs are treated as
> different apps in Google Play Store

> To create the link, you need to know the app's fully qualified
> package name, which is declared in the app's manifest file. The
> package name is also visible in the Google Play Console.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id
https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play?hl=de

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Does it mean creating a new app in play console in the way  I did at first for this app? I have my own console and I am new.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed the link you inserted and got a alternative solution!